# Solving the path integral for a relativistic point particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral

I am studying chapter 9 of Polyakov's ``Gauge Fields and Strings". The problem is to solve the path integral:

$$\mathcal{A}=\int \mathcal{D}X e^{-m\int _{0}^{1}d\tau \sqrt{-\dot{X}^2}}.$$

The domain of integration is the set of all curves in the target space $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{R}^D$ with fixed boundaries $X_1$ and $X_2$

The other textbooks instead refrain from calculating the path integral with non-polynomial actions as the one written above. I am interested in studying Polyakov's calculation. However, I find the arguments hard to follow. Is there any other resource that solves the same problem?

Comment: Which of the arguments is hard to follow? Polyakov’s method is to replace this path integral with the equivalent  that is quadratic in $x$ and hence solvable. What do you not understand — the equivalence, or how to solve the quadratic in $x$ path integral?

Comment: I can actually follow the arguments. However, I am not entirely satisfied as I think I would not be able to come up with this on my own. I also think there are some Jacobian factors missing.

Comment: how about asking a specific question about the missing factors then? Also no offense, but the fact that you wouldn’t be able to come up with something does not say anything objective about that thing at all.

Comment: One thing I found hard to follow is when he evaluates the $X$ integral using the law of large numbers.

Comment: I suggest you use this website to its full potential and ask a separate question about this, giving all details in the question to make it self-contained. Let me know when you do, I might want to take a look — I have studied this stuff awhile ago and I still remember some of it.